# Native Dropdown using Ionic framework

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015

I am using ionic + cordova on Visual Studio 2015

Is it possible to create native like dropdown using Ionic framework?

The current dropdown looks like http://play.ionic.io/app/3e4c1f91d962 this is not much appealing on device. Further, on Android device the text for option goes blank. However, only after selection, it shows the text.

Can we show it like the first image shown at http://baymard.com/blog/mobile-dropdown-navigation

Comment: I think android is not a revelant tag for your issue.

Comment: ok. The issue of blank option is observed only on Android, it works well on Ripple emulator. And, so I added the Android tag.

Comment: There is a similar case that might help: [iPhone / Android induce native Dropdown picker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490287/iphone-android-induce-native-dropdown-picker)

Comment: but it says "<select> does not work on Android 4.4.2 when used in WebView with Phonegap"

Comment: I tried incorporating the example, however on Android tab, it shows dropdown without any text. It shows all the options as blank text, upon selection the dropdown shows correct selected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now the issue with this is that the `<select>` tags are "Platform Specific" I am using the `<select multiple="true">` and the simple `<select>` tag on a hybrid app for iOS and android. On android it looks hideous, but on iOS it looks nice. That is something we can't really control. If you want to have a really nice looking dropdown, you might have to find a different way for drop downs other than HTML.